# Webpart not displaying on IE

Tags: web-part

I have a very weird problem, I have a custom webpart that displaying on Edge and Chrome and not IE. Having said that when I change the page to edit mode, the webpart is visible on IE too and when I stop editing it will disappear. I have tried with different version of IE and all of them having the same issue.

Regards

[image]

Comment: It's hard to know the cause without an error.  What is in the browser console in IE when it doesn't display?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is something wrong with your scripts that stopping the webpart to show up in IE.

SharePoint page is adding / removing classes or DOM elements when editing and publishing the page so there should be some culprit that making your webpart error.

In IE have you checked your console during the page load? you can see by pressing f12 and then click on the console tab like the screen shot below;

[image]

so we could investigate more and see if what causes the problem.

Hope the concept helps, happy learning!

Comment: I have attached the screenshot from the location you mentioned. not sure if those error messages related to my issue.

Comment: Do you get the mapcontrol.ashx error in other browsers?  That looks like the cause at a glance.

Comment: Sorry for getting back late, have you resolved the toLoweCase issue? it is said that you are calling the method from an undefined or null value.

let us know if it got resolved. Regards!